# Method of a service with component as argument -It is a bad convention?

Tags: angular

I´m developing an angular app and I´m creating a method inside service which needs a component as argument.

MyService:

```
myMethodInsideService(myComponent: MyComponent){}
```

This is a bad convention? What is the problems by using this?

Comment: it depends what you're trying to do, what does this method do?

Comment: Its fine, Just avoid cyclic dependency

Comment: @Ravi Rajput what do you mean cyclic dependency? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Cyclic dependency means, you should not use this service in the component you are passing as argument.

Comment: I don't known situation then you have to use component as variable type. If you need to send some data (not whole component) it is better to use class which describe needed data.